# Both fullWidth and className on a MUI component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to use both  className and fullWidth properties on a Material UI TextField component, but this doesn't seem to work.

Using just className works fine, and just the fullWidth works fine aswell but when I try to use both it only listens to className.

```
//Only className, works fine
<TextField
    id="date"
    label="Only className"
    type="date"
    defaultValue="2017-05-23"
    className={classes.textField}
    InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true
    }}
/>
//Only fullWidth, works fine
<TextField
    id="date"
    label="Only fullWidth"
    type="date"
    defaultValue="2017-05-24"
    fullWidth={true}
    InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true
    }}
/>
//Both, not working (only className is applied)
<TextField
    id="date"
    label="Both"
    type="date"
    defaultValue="2017-05-25"
    className={classes.textField}
    fullWidth={true}
    InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true
    }}
/>
```

**Sandbox example:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-0qqqd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `TextField` style you are overriding `fullWidth` prop by giving your own width of 200px .

```
textField: {
  marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
  marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  width: 200
}
```

change it to :

```
textField: {
  marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
  marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  width: '100%'
}
```

**or**

just remove the width from textField style

```
textField: {
  marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
  marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
}
```

then in your TextField use `fullWidth=true`

```
  <TextField
    id="date"
    label="Birthday"
    type="date"
    defaultValue="2017-05-25"
    className={classes.textField}
    fullWidth={true}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true
    }}
  />
```

Comment: Alright, that works. But what if I want to have a default width, 200px, and recieve fullWidth via props? Would I have to use css width 100% then?

Comment: use a minimum width ... minWidth:200